# 2 divs have about 1px gap in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

IE 10 and 11 hasn't disappointed me so much when it comes to css until today . .

The class `base` and `triangle` has about 1px gap in between in IE 9 - 11. The other 4 browsers are not showing the gap.

```
.base {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: -8px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #5A5A5A;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:0;
}
.triangle {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 0 11px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #DBB004;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 24px;
    right: -8px;
    margin:0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WrVYd/7/)

Comment: I can see the gap even in Chrome on OS X. Your triangle element seems positioned one pixel higher than should be.

Comment: Its actually lower and bigger than it should be so that ff will show the same that's why the `.triangle` has a `z-index:-1`. Its actually showing perfectly inn Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari on W7. . Does that mean chrome would render differently on other OS versions?

Comment: I think you should define a line height on `.base`.

Comment: Also "Safari on W7"? WTH? There is only ancient version 5 available for Windows, you should probably be testing versions 6 and 7.

Comment: There's a 1 pixel gap in all Mac browsers. I agree with Pavlo about the line height. You need more control over the height of the text box. Perhaps a better approach is to create the triangle using `.base:after` or `.base:before`.

Comment: Really now in all Mac browsers? Didn't see that coming. Best to find a good free browser tester then. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug. This is the correct rendering of `display: inline-block;` elements by the browser. The browser spaces inline-block elements using a width equal to a single white space character of the font (therefore, the larger the font, the wider the gap).

**You can read how to solve this issue at [CSS Tricks here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**. However, generally a negative margin-left of -4px (if your body font size is 16px) will remove the white space. For example:

```
.element {
    display: inline-block;
}

.element ~ .element {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

### Edit

A better way of handling the white-space is to set `font-size: 0;` on the parent element and reset the `font-size: 18px;` or whatever your body font-size is on each of the elements with `display: inline-block;` elements`. This will handle browser zooming and hires displays better than the method I described above. Obviously, this strategy sometimes require an additional parent element, which might break your layout styling.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a horizontal gap between two divs and was able to resolve it by setting  `{ margin-top: -1px; }`

Answer (score 1):

Change the `.triangle` margin to `-1px`.

Comment: I think this works because of margin collapse, though I didn't expect it to because the elements are positioned absolutely.

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements don't get affected by margin collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving it, is by putting the triangle inside the base-element. Easiest would to replace it with an `::after` pseduo-element.

```
.base::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 0 11px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #DBB004;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 0px;
    margin:0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WrVYd/21/